# How to change llvm version for m1 Mac to build Haskell project

Tags: haskell, clang, llvm, apple-m1

I am trying to build a Haskell project but I keep getting this error:

```
    You are using an unsupported version of LLVM!
    Currently only 9 to 13 is supported. System LLVM version: 15.0.7
We will try though...
Cannot specify -O# and --passes=/--foo-pass, use -passes='default<O#>,other-pass'
`opt' failed in phase `LLVM Optimiser'. (Exit code: 1)
```

I installed llvm@12 using homebrew and tried changing the PATH variable but I could not get the system LLVM version to change. How do I ensure the system LLVM version is llvm@12?

Comment: try using: `brew unlink llvm` and then `brew link llvm@12`